# How does the default work here and how does the get method have 2 arguments in it and why are there () at the end?

Tags: python, getmethod

```py
def spring():
  return "It is Spring"
def summer():
  return "It is Summer"
def autumn():
  return "It is Autumn"
def winter():
  return "It is Winter"
def default():
  return "Invalid Season!"

switch_case = {
  1: spring,
  2: summer,
  3: autumn,
  4: winter
}

def switch(x):
  return switch_case.get(x, default)()

y= int(input("enter a number for 4 seasons"))
print (switch(y))
```

I tried removing the `()` from the end and it doesn't return the default value anymore. When the `()`
was placed right after default it didn't return any value when an input between 1 to 4 was made.

Comment: The values in your dictionary are functions.  Thus, `switch_case[1]` returns a function.  To call that function, you need to use parens like any other function: `switch_case[1]()`.  It's an ordinary function call with an unusual name.  ;)  The first parameter to `dict.get` is the label to look up.  The second parameter is what to return if that key is not found.

Comment: You could do `print(switch_case.get(1))` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing the `dict` is supposed to return *some* function, no matter what key is presented. `default` is returned when the key `x` doesn't exist. Whatever function *does* get returned is immediately called.

`switch` could  be defined more verbosely as

```
def switch(x):
    try:
        f = switch_case[x]
    except KeyError:
        f = default
    return f()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code returns the result of the function retrieved by the `.get(...)` call:

```
return switch_case.get(x, default)()

# --- equivalent ---
fn = switch_case.get(x, default)
return fn()
```

This code returns a function, but doesn't call it:

```
return switch_case.get(x, default)
```

Using this construction you could return the function and then call it later:

```
def switch(x):
  return switch_case.get(x, default)

y = int(input("enter a number for 4 seasons"))
fn = switch(y)
print(fn())  # call the "switched" function here
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you put the function object in the dictionary. Suppose you were using the function directly:

```
def spring():
    return "It is Spring"

spring()
```

This tells python to load the object in the variable `spring` and call it. It had better be a callable object, or python will raise an error. It will follow those same steps, regardless of whether the object is really correct. For instance

```
>>> foo = 1
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The same thing happened with your dictionary. `switch_case.get(x, default)` gets the function object from the dictionary, but you still have to call it.

```
>>> switch_case.get(1, default)
<function spring at 0x7efed8413d90>
>>> switch_case.get(1, default)()
'It is Spring'
```